# Как параллельно выводить значок загрузки и выполнять действия с бд?

Tags: python, flask

Я начинающий в веб разработке, у меня есть сервер на flask, который хостится на pythonanywhere. Я поднял MySQL server, настроил её работу с flask, но есть такая проблема: мне надо, что бы при переходе на вкладку шла загрузка, и параллельно записывались данные в бд, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Думаю примерно так: при клике на вкладку, нужно будет отправлять ajax запрос на сервер и отобразить на странице прогрессбар (например гифку), пока сервер обрабатывает запрос прогрессбар будет крутиться, как придет от сервера ответ, нужно будет его отобразить на вкладке и убрать прогрессбар . Для удобства можно использовать jquery с его методом ajax (у метода есть всякие полезные обработчики типа `oncomplete`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flaks - это web-фреймворк. Начинающему разработчику важно понимать два важных факта о web-разработке:

1. Любое [web-приложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) на самом деле состоит из двух приложений, написанных на разных языках, работающих на разных машинах и в разное время - фронтенда и бэкенда<sup>1</sup>.
2. Фронтенд и бэкенд обмениваются данными по протоколу [HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP), а это протокол без состояния<sup>2</sup>, работающий в режиме запрос-ответ. Это значит, что у фронта и бэка нет постоянной связи. В тот момент, когда вы видите в браузере страницу, код сгенерировавший её на сервере давно завершился.

Из этих двух факторов вырастает множество отличий в разработке web-приложений от любой другой разработки. Например, длительные задачи не должны выполняться в обработчиках запроса<sup>3</sup>, а логика взаимодействия с пользователем не должна предполагать ожидания чего-либо.

Конечно, есть способы сглаживающие эти особенности - [AJAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX), [SSE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events), [Websockets](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) и прочее. Например вэбсокеты позволяют фронту и бэку обмениваться данными в режиме реального времени. Они хорошо подойдут для вашей задачи. Вот только Flask не подходит для вэбсокетов, для них нужен какой-нибудь асинхронный фреймворк<sup>4</sup>.

---

1. Иногда фронтенд - это полноценное приложение с логикой, а иногда редуцированное до примитивного html-интерфейса.
2. Ну, в изначальной основе. Есть костылики, исправляющие это неудобство - [Cookie](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie). Но всё равно про это ограничение важно знать и важно его учитывать, чтобы делать хорошие web-приложения.
3. Их стоит перекладывать на фоновые сервисы, типа [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).
4. Например [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp).

Comment: Кст, у flask'а видел socketio: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO

Comment: @gil9red не заглядывал в его код, но зато провёл немало времени в коде Flask, а там чуть ли не каждая строка построена на предположении, что код работает синхронно. Поэтому меня несколько настораживает попытки его асинхронного применения. Впрочем, ещё более синхронный Django удалось напялить на Daphne с помощью Channels, может и тут тоже хорошо сделано.